# How to spark-submit a python file in spark 2.1.0?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

I am currently running spark 2.1.0. I have worked most of the time in PYSPARK shell, but I need to spark-submit a python file(similar to spark-submit jar in java) . How do you do that in python?

Answer (score 11):

pythonfile.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("appName").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
print(rdd.count())
```

Run the above program with configurations you want : eg :

```
 YOUR_SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master yourSparkMaster --num-executors 20 \
        --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 1G \
        pythonfile.py
```

These options are not mandatory. You can even run like

```
YOUR_SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master sparkMaster/local pythonfile.py
```